# Magento 2 - Query to know the user who update the price of the product

Tags: sql, query

I am very new to magento. What is the query to to know who was the user who updated the price of a product?

I just want to know the query, not the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about which admin user updates a product via the admin, this info will only exist if you're using the Commerce version. If you're using the community version I'm afraid this data won't exist in Magento. There are lots of custom modules that will log this info from the admin.

If you are using Commerce, you can run:

```
SELECT e.*,JSON_EXTRACT(info,'$.general') FROM magento.magento_logging_event e
where event_code = 'catalog_products'
and JSON_EXTRACT(info,'$.general') = "<ID of the product>"
```

This will show you who has saved that product and when, but it doesn't have the data to show what specifically was updated.